# Looking for title of Superhero ebook

Tags: story-identification

I read about this book on Amazon a couple of years ago. All I can recall is that it's about a superhero who wakes up and finds his universe had been retconed. He's no longer married and the people who respected him are now frightened of him. I think it was for Kindle but may be a print book, Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - This was a prose story not a graphic novel. It came out within the last 5 or 6 years.

Comment: Can you remember whether it was a pre-existing superhero, or one created especially for the story?

Comment: One created for the story

Comment: Have you tried looking through TV tropes. Without some more details I'm not sure which of these would apply, but you might try looking under Retcon, Cosmic Retcon (a big in-universe event caused a retcon), Retconjuration (for characters who can create cosmic retcons), Ripple Effect-Proof Memory (since the main characters remembers the pre-retcon universe)